# react component composition pass props with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Scenario: create a context menu that is opened via an icon and when the menu is open, the icon should change colour to indicate that it is active/open

Depending where the icon is, the colours change slightly. I have a few ideas and not sure if one of them is possible...

```
type ContextMenuProps = {
  children: JSX.Element;
  items: ItemsType; // defined somewhere else...
}

const ContextMenu = ({chlidren}: ContextMenuProps ) => {
  
  // This needs to be passed into children
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  { // some other code }

  <children.type {...children.props} isOpen={isOpen} />

}

<ContextMenu>



</ContextMenu>
```

```
// another component


// It works if I leave it as an optional prop, is there a way to get it to work without being optional?
type PageHeaderContextIconProps = { isOpen?: boolean };

const PageHeaderContextIcon = ({ isOpen }: PageHeaderContextIconProps) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.button} ${isOpen ? styles.active : ''}`}>
            <ContextMenuIcon />
        </div>
    );
};

// Render the menu with our icon...
<ContextMenu
    items={pageMenuItems}   
>
    <PageHeaderContextIcon />
</ContextMenu>
```

As you can see by the comment above the code, it works when the type is defined as optional. Is there a way to remove the `?` or even a better pattern for this?

Comment: There are lots of ways to skin this cat, it's best to keep it simple. What you're doing right now is simple. You're using well understood patterns and syntax to indicate that something is indeed optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove the '?', you have to pass the isOpen prop a true or false value everywhere you have used PageHeaderContextIcon.

```
<ContextMenu items={pageMenuItems}>
    // In case of menu is closed and you don't want to show the color indicating active/open.
    <PageHeaderContextIcon isOpen={false} />
</ContextMenu>
```

OR

```
<ContextMenu items={pageMenuItems}>
    // In case of menu is OPEN and you want to show the color indicating active/open.
    <PageHeaderContextIcon isOpen />
</ContextMenu>
```

This will help you to get rid of the optional '?'. It will throw an error if you didn't pass any prop and still make it required.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this off, I ended up using a render prop...

```
type ContextMenuProps = {
  trigger: (isOpen: boolean) => JSX.Element;
  items: ItemsType; // defined somewhere else...
}

const ContextMenu = ({chlidren}: ContextMenuProps ) => {
  
  // This needs to be passed into children
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  { // some other code }

  <>
   {trigger(isOpen)}
  </>

}

// And to use it

<ContextMenu 
   items={menuItems} 
   trigger={ (isOpen) => { 
             <TriggerCompoennt isOpen={isOpen }/>}} 
/>
```